# Revoking extended permission from facebook settings

Tags: facebook

I am using facebook PHP SDK and using that I can able to make request to facebook and get the expended permission from user. After user granted extended permission, anytime user can remove our application or revoke certain granted permission from their settings page, but there is a call back url for facebook to notify, so that and we can track who has removed our application, Suppose some one revoke certain granted permission instead of removing application, How facebook notify us to trace which permission has been revoked by the user?

Is there any other way our app to get to know, what are the permissions user has granted?

Thanks.

-Ravi

Answer (score 0):

You can check if user gave some particular permission with [users.hasAppPermission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.hasAppPermission)

Comment: But in this case, every permission I have to sent request to facebook and which will take time also. What I want is that whenever I command FB to display permission dialog box, when user click 'allow' button, I know what are permissions I put in dialog box and I can store in database. If some one revoke permission, if FB notify that I can remove permission from user's permission list in database.